# Page reloaded automatically after sometime in aspnet core with angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core

I am developping a web application using **AspNet Core** with **AngualrJS**.

I have a problem when a page is opened for sometime and I want to navigate to another page or click on save button. The page **reload automatically sending me to default route** which is home. And I lose the data entered in the form.

In the console it's written "**result undefined**" and refering to the service I am calling, exactly to the return line.

Here is an example of service :

```
function GetMessage(id) {

    var promise = $http.post('api/Gestion/GetMessage', id).then(
        function (data) {
            return data.data;
        }).catch(queryFailed);

    return promise;

}
```

The **same thing happen after publishing** some changes to the server.

In my opinion, it's like if the session is destroyed after some minutes.

Do you have any idea how can I remove this delay, and let the session persist if it's really the cause.

And for reloading after publishing, do you suggest a better way to do it transparenlty, instead of losing work of people working on it live.

I am new to this technology, don't hesitate please to change the description to make it too specific if you know the problem

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me :
https://cypressnorth.com/programming/solved-using-memory-repository-keys-will-not-persisted-storage-asp-net-core-iis/

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes it might be wise to log errors:

```
function GetMessage(id) {

    var promise = $http.post('api/Gestion/GetMessage', id).then(
        function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }).catch(function(response) {
            console.log("GetMessage ERROR", response);
            queryFailed(response);
        });

    return promise;    
}
```

Also keep in mind that the `queryFailed` function needs to `throw` the response:

```
function queryFailed(response) {
    //
    // fail handler code here
    //
    throw response;
}
```

If the function lacks a throw statement, the promise will be **converted** from a rejected promise to a successful promise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Yes the queryFailed function is throwing that error and it's saying that "result is undefined" refering to the function GetMessage for example